# No sign-in authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookie("Identity.Application",...)?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

so Im traing to auth a user and i'm stuck on this error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No sign-in authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookie("Identity.Application",...)?

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.SignInAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, ClaimsPrincipal principal, AuthenticationProperties properties)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.SignInWithClaimsAsync(TUser user, AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties, IEnumerable`1 additionalClaims)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.SignInOrTwoFactorAsync(TUser user, Boolean isPersistent, String loginProvider, Boolean bypassTwoFactor)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.PasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, String password, Boolean isPersistent, Boolean lockoutOnFailure)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.PasswordSignInAsync(String userName, String password, Boolean isPersistent, Boolean lockoutOnFailure)

   at ApplicationCore.Infrastructure.Services.IdentityService.SigninUserAsync(String userName, String password) in C:\Users\Radhoine\source\repos\ApplicationCore\ApplicationCore.Infrastructure\Services\IdentityService.cs:line 218

   at ApplicationCore.Application.Commands.Auth.AuthCommandHandler.Handle(AuthCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\Radhoine\source\repos\ApplicationCore\ApplicationCore.Application\Commands\Auth\AuthCommand.cs:line 32

   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)

   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)

   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionActionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)

   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionActionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)

   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)

   at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)

   at ApplicationCore.API.Controllers.AuthController.Login(AuthCommand command) in C:\Users\Radhoine\source\repos\ApplicationCore\ApplicationCore.API\Controllers\AuthController.cs:line 23

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()

--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)

   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

here is my code

> in program.cs

```
var _key = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"];
var _issuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"];
var _audience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"];
var _expirtyMinutes = builder.Configuration["Jwt:ExpiryMinutes"];


// Configuration for token
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidAudience = _audience,
        ValidIssuer = _issuer,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_key)),
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(_expirtyMinutes))

    };
});


// Dependency injection with key
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITokenGenerator>(new TokenGenerator(_key, _issuer, _audience, _expirtyMinutes));


// Include Infrastructur Dependency
builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);
```

> Here my IdentityService class

```
public class IdentityService : IIdentityService
    {
        private readonly UserManager<PartenaireContact> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<PartenaireContact> _signInManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

        public IdentityService(UserManager<PartenaireContact> userManager, SignInManager<PartenaireContact> signInManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }

       


        public async Task<bool> SigninUserAsync(string userName, string password)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, true, false);
            return result.Succeeded;


        }

    }
```

So what i'm missing? or what's wrong?
Im using .net 6
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So I solved this by changing the sign in method from

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, true, false);
            return result.Succeeded;
```

To

```
var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(...);
return result.Succeeded;
```

Thank you